# use jquery to load different divs into popup div

Tags: jquery, popup, replacewith

I have a popup div that I need to load a bunch of different divs with custom ids.

for example say we have recipepopup1 recipepopup2 and recipepopup3 each of which have a recipebutton1, recipebutton2 recipebutton3 respectively  and then we have another div to load the recipepopup1..recipepopup3 into called recipe_popup.

how can i have it so when i click button1 it will load div1 into popupdiv and if i click button2 it will load div2 into recipe_display etc.

right now I am using replaceWith() and i have found that it replaces the id of the recipe_pop div with recipepopup1 when i click button1 so when i click recipepopup2 it just loads the div outside of the recipe_popup div

one more thing to note is that each of the recipepopup should be able to be loaded infinitely many times - so when i close the popup and click a recipebutton that has already been clicked it will still popup the relevant div

thanks for any help :)
katie
here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#recipebutton1").click(function(){
        $('#create_form_span').css('display', 'none');
        $(".recipepopup").css('display','none');
        $("#recipe_display").replaceWith($('#recipepopup1').css('display','block'));
    });
    $("#recipebutton2").click(function(){
        $('#create_form_span').css('display', 'none');
        $(".recipepopup").css('display','none');
        $("#recipe_display").replaceWith($('#recipepopup2').css('display','block'));
    });
    $("#recipebutton3").click(function(){
        $('#create_form_span').css('display', 'none');
        $(".recipepopup").css('display','none');
        $("#recipe_display").replaceWith($('#recipepopup3').css('display','block'));
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use $("#recipe_display").html($('#recipepopup2').html())

Hope it helps.